# Microsoft Academic API, Knowledge graph search -- ReferenceIDs always empty

Tags: json, web-services, api, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the [graph search](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Academic-Knowledge-API/documentation/GraphSearchMethod) method of the Microsoft Academic API to retrieve citation IDs and reference IDs for a paper. However, while retrieving citation IDs works, the reference IDs field is always empty, even for papers which should have linked references. For example, retrieving [this publication](https://academic.microsoft.com/#/detail/2059999322) through the API:

```
POST https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/graph/search?mode=json
Content-Type: application/json
Host: westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: my-api-key

{  
    "path": "/paper",
    "paper": {  
        "select": [  
            "OriginalTitle",
            "CitationIDs",
            "ReferenceIDs"
        ],
        "type": "Paper",
        "id": [2059999322]
    }
}
```

yields this response (I shortened the CitationIDs list for the sake of legibility):

```
{
    "Results": [
        [
            {
                "CellID": 2059999322, 
                "CitationIDs": "[630584464,2053566310,2239657960,...]",  
                "OriginalTitle": "Biodistribution of colloidal gold nanoparticles after intravenous administration: Effect of particle size", 
                "ReferenceIDs": ""
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

One thing I've noticed is that the graph schema provided [here](https://www.graphengine.io/docs/apis/mag.html) (at the bottom of the page) doesn't match the schema shown [here](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Academic-Knowledge-API/documentation/GraphSearchMethod) (some of the attributes were renamed, e.g. NormalizedPaperTitle -> NormalizedTitle), so I thought the field was perhaps renamed to something else.

What is the correct query to get reference IDs through the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `ReferencesIDs`, not `ReferenceIDs`

Comment: To see which fields are available, you can use "*" in the "select" field (at least that works for lambda queries...)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I just tried, it works for json queries too.