# Retrieving citations of a given paper using Microsoft's Academic Evaluate API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Using Microsoft's Cognitive Lab's Academic API, is there a means to retrieve the papers which have cited a given paper?

Relevant documentation I've already read:
[Attributes Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/paperentityattributes)

Comment: The best way to do this will be to explore the Graph. You can find some hints @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489315/microsoft-academic-api-knowledge-graph-search-referenceids-always-empty

Comment: I've had a look at the graph schema (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/graphsearchmethod#graph-schema), but it doesn't indicate a path for retrieving papers which cite a given paper (as opposed to getting citation for a given paper, I'm looking for the inverse of this). Could you give some further insight on this. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to retrieve citations to an article (in this case all articles citing article with id 1540483997), I used a request like this one:

https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?&expr=RId=1540483997&count=1000&attributes=Ti,RId&subscription-key=<subscription_key>

Answer (score 0):

I've been fiddling with the API myself and can't find a way to do this. It would be great for Microsoft Academic to add this feature since it would allow us to do a Eigenvector analysis of our institution's research output.

I've been able to extend API functionality a little (like sending one call to get data for a specific list of papers) by analyzing the URL of the search interface and what I see for the citations page indicates to me that there is no code for this value. Note the "q=papers+citing" part of the url. :-(
https://academic.microsoft.com/#/search?iq=And(Ty='0',RId=2072682145)&q=papers+citing+public+debt and+growth+heterogeneity+and+non+linearity&filters=&from=0&sort=0